# What kind of Shower fitting can I install in a stock tank to tub conversion?

Tags: plumbing, shower, drain

I have a 4ft stock tank (something like this: https://www.lowes.com/pd/tarter-71-gallon-galvanized-steel-stock-tank/3159637) and an almost done tiny house.

I'm trying to convert it into a tub with a shower. Knowing nothing about plumbing I purchased this [https://www.amazon.com/Oatey-42099-NO-CALK-Stainless-Strainer/dp/B000BO57AS](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B000BO57AS) only to realize it comes up very far off the flat floor of the stock tank. I only realized this after I drilled a 2.5 inch hole in the floor. eek!

What kind of drain can I use to get the flattest possible drain? It doesn't have to be totally flat, but close enough. Is there a name for what I need? Everything I've found so far on amazon and lowes seems to be geared for tile or fiberglass installs.

Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There are certainly bath tub drains that will work on thin metal tubs but often these have a stamped round depression around the drain hole that causes the drain top to be more level with the surrounding tub floor. This picture shows what this looks like from the side.

[image]

<sup>*(Picture Source: https://edmondbathtubrefinishing.com/bathtub-plumbing-installation-drain-diagrams/)*</sup>

Maybe this particular all metal type drain will be more suitable for your application. The top side flange of a metal drain will be thinner than a plastic one due to metal being stronger.

[image]

<sup>*(Picture Source: [https://www.amazon.com/KOHLER-K-9132-CP-Shower-Polished-Chrome/dp/B0014YLQE0](https://rads.stackoverflow.com/amzn/click/com/B0014YLQE0))*</sup>